# GLB/GLTF file not exporting anything correctly with /blend file with precise dimensions

Tags: export, gltf

I sincerely have no idea what's wrong with my blend file, but for whatever reason, in blender 2.79 on linux, when exporting to a GLB or GLTF (either with option Selected Objects or without, with "normals" selected etc.) it only exports part of the objects, and either most of them are in the wrong position, or openly cut out etc., I've never seen anything like it.

The only thing that may be different is because in this blend file I tried setting the units the meters and precisely measuring in edit mode

When exporting everything without "Selected Objects", they appear to be in the correct position, but all of the edited boxes appear just as 1x1x1 (when each one was fixed in edit mode to be a precise measurement).

It's hard to describe it but [here's the .blend file with some examples of attempted GLTF exports.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1L1GQT_ITE1bMLcBE6__mUBaFNNLdWhit?usp=sharing)

It should be noted that I made all of the normals recalculate out, but not sure if that affected it because either way most things were still cut out or in the wrong position etc.

It also should be noted that if I only export one object with "Selected Objects" applied, it works fine, but any more than 1 it messes everything up?

Comment: Try using an up-to-date Blender version (3.2). The 2.79 glTF exporter is out of date and buggy.

Comment: @scurest 3.2 doesnt work on my device

Comment: @B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem what do you mean doesn't work on your device? what device are you using? what does command `lsb_release -a` on your system output? and have you tried `sudo snap install blender --classic`? That's what I used to install blender 3.2

Comment: @harry I don't have snap standard Ubuntu I think version 4

Comment: can you share your system output using command `lsb_release -a`